# $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ open, $f:[0,1] \to A$ continous. Show $\exists$ piecewise linear function $g:[0,1] \to A$ with $g(0)=f(0), g(1)=f(1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, connectedness

> $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ open, $f:[0,1] \to A$ continous. Show $\exists$ peacewise linear function $g:[0,1] \to A$ with $g(0)=f(0), g(1)=f(1)$

I think it should be enough to show it for $\mathbb R$ instead of $\mathbb R^n$ as one can apply it in every component.
So far I don't have any approaches. Is it possible to construct the function explicitly or do I only show the existence?
I am not too sure about the right tags for this question either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That would fulfill the equations but I can't see why it is piecewise linear?

Comment: Sorry, I've got now your question. I think you should add the tags "topology" and "connection"

Comment: Hints: (i) If $A$ is convex (e.g., if $A$ is a Euclidean ball) this is trivial. (ii) Show that the (compact!) image $f([0, 1])$ can be covered by finitely many open balls, each contained in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch of the proof:

Take $t_0 = 0$ and suppose $t_n$ is defined. Then $\exists \delta, \rho > 0 : f([t_n, t_n + \delta]) \subset B(f(t_n), \rho) \subset A$, since $A$ is open and $f$ continuous. Define $t_{n+1} = t_n + \delta$. Clearly, $\{t_n\}$ is strictly increasing and bounded by $1$, so it must converge.

Suppose $\{t_n\} \to \alpha < 1$. Then $\exists \rho : B(f(\alpha), \rho) \subset A$, and $\exists N : f(t_n) \in B(f(\alpha), \rho) \forall n \ge N$ since $f$ is continuous. Redefine $t_{N+1} = \alpha$.

If $\{t_n\} < 1 \forall n$ you can use the same trick above and get a finite collection of $t_n$ with $t_0 = 0, t_N=1$.

Finally, $[f(t_n), f(t_{n+1})] \subset A \forall n \in \Bbb N$, so for $x \in [0,1[ ,\;\exists! n : t_n \le x < t_{n+1}$. Define $g(x) = \frac{x - t_n}{t_{n+1} - t_n}(f(t_{n+1})-f(t_n)), g(1) = f(1)$. Checking the continuity of $g$ is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks, but at which point does the piecewise linear function $g$ come into play?

Comment: See my edit @PeterGarder